# Segmentation Fault when writing to a file in C

Tags: c, io, segmentation-fault

Whenever I attempt to write to a file, I am getting a segmentation fault.  I don't have any access to software that can tell me where it's coming from since I'm at school.  If anyone could help me out that would be great.

```
//OLMHash.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "OLMHash.h"

int main()
{
    createAccount();
    return 0;
}

struct account createAccount()
{


    struct account *newAccount;
    newAccount = (struct account *)malloc(sizeof(struct account));

    printf("Enter userid: ");
    scanf("%s", newAccount->userid);
    printf("\nEnter password: ");
    scanf("%s", newAccount->password);

    char *output = malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
    strcpy(output, newAccount->userid);
    strcat(output, "\t");
    strcat(output, newAccount->password);

    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("accountslist.txt", "r");
    fputs(newAccount->userid, fp);

    free(output);
}
```

-

```
//OLMHash.h

struct account
{
    char userid[32];
    char password[12];  

};

struct account createAccount();
```

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: You opened the file for reading, not writing. And please *always* check the return value from `fopen()`.

Comment: Casts for malloc in C is a bad idea - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: I think I've solved it.  Weather Vane had it right.  I was opening the file for reading when the file didn't even exist yet.  After physically creating the file the error disappeared.  Thank you

Comment: Think what will happen when the user is entering a *long* name or password...

Comment: Why allocate `output` if you don't use it? Why doesn't your function return what it should return? Why didn't you compile with warnings on?

Comment: Note too that you didn't close the file - every open has a close, every malloc has a free, etc., etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

You opened the file for reading instead of writing, and you did not check the action succeeded. Try

```
fp = fopen("accountslist.txt", "w");
if(fp == NULL) {
    // get out code
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When calling fopen, I was opening it for reading rather than writing.  I physically created the file that way I can leave it as "reading"

Comment: And always, *always*, check the return of `scanf`. Otherwise, you have no idea if you are processing actual values or garbage.

Comment: If you want to WRITE to a file, then open it for WRITING.